# modulo type constraints in gekko

Tags: python, python-3.x, gekko

I would like to know whether it's possible to add, with a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming solver (such as the [APOPT](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) solver), an integer constraint like: a variable should be a multiple of 5, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can get values other than 0,1,2,etc by introducing a scaling factor with the integer variable. This involves defining a new variable (y) such as:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(integer=True,lb=0,ub=10)
y = m.Intermediate(x*5)
m.Obj((y-17)**2)
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()

print(y.value)
```

This finds the value of y that is a multiple of 5 and that is closest to the value of 17. In this case, it finds that 15 is optimal.

*John Hedengren from BYU kindly gave me this suggestion.*

Comment: Janus, thanks for adding your question and the response from the e-mail discussion group. It helps to have questions like this on StackOverflow where search engines can more easily help those who have similar questions to find answers.

Comment: Hi Prof, thanks for your work on the package ! i will try from time to time to get more questions from the e-mail discussion group posted here, starting by the most recent ones. I hope it will help as many people as possible !

Comment: Thanks for adding the questions. On stackoverflow, we'll often need to reduce the question to a minimal example so that the question and answer are more broadly applicable.